# SQLite Join Query on Two Tables in Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am new in Xamarin forms & currently developing an app providing offline data access. For offline feature I have created SQLite database & mulitple tables. Now when I am trying to fetch data using Join, I am unable to perform the task. Below is the code

```
public Thoughts GetQueryForAllRecords(int ID)
{
    var q = connection.Query<Thoughts>("SELECT Thought,CreatedOn, AssignedToName, AssignedOn FROM Thoughts JOIN AssignedThought ON Thoughts.ID = AssignedThought.ID where Thoughts.ID=?;", ID);

    return q.Last(t => t.ID == ID);
}
```

'Thoughts' and 'AssignedThought' are two tables. In above code, i am only getting records for one table i.e. Thoughts. If I am changing generic type to 'AssignedThought' then it shows me only AssignedThought records.

Can any one suggest me what am I doing wrong here? I want to perform join operation to get records from both table.

Comment: Your join looks like it's done correctly. Without seeing the table schema, I would guess that your problem is with `Thoughts.ID = AssignedThought.ID`. Typically an ID column is the primary key of a table, but it sounds like AssignedThought is a join table, and you should be joining in your Thoughts table on a foreign key. If you have a column like `AssignedThought.ThoughtID`, you should probably be joining on that column, instead of `AssignedThought.ID`. If you are still trying to fix this problem, can you post the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

Does both tables have same properties? Else you have to create a DTO Table with required properties from both the tables and use it as generic type